# mongo set new field in query results based on existence and rank of other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Every document in collection may potentially have none/some/all of `val1`, `val2`, `val3` as fields. I'd like to make a query that returns a result that, in its projection, sets a field `top_val` that is simply value of `val1`, or if that doesn't exist, then `va2`, or if that doesn't exist, `val3`.
In pseudo-code, something like:

`collection.find({ <condition> }, { "top_val": { "$val1" or "$val2" or "$val3" } )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `$ifNull`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "top_val": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$valA",
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$valB",
              "$valC"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8JV0SOjzDwd)